# Do Cauchy always converge (for some superset)?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

I know Cauchy sequences are only guaranteed converge in complete metric spaces.

However, I have been struggling with one issue. It seems that every Cauchy sequence converges, at least in a larger metric space (using the same distance function). Is the following conjecture true or false? (I'm almost sure it is false, but I cannot find a counter-example).

**Conjecture**: Let $X_{n}$ be a Cauchy sequence in an incomplete metric space $(M,d_M)$. Suppose $X_{n}$ does not converge in $(M,d_M)$. Then, there exists a metric space $(N,d_M)$, where $N \supseteq M$ , endowed with the same distance function $d_M$ such that $X_{n}$ converges in $(N,d_M)$.

Comment: Yes it is true: given any metric space, you can form its [Cauchy completion using equivalence classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space#Completion). Indeed, this technique is one of the ways of constructing $\Bbb R$ from $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: It is true. More than that you can choose $N$ such that $M$ will be dense in it. This is one of the ways to define real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can say this is true.

Lets say that cauchy sequence $\{a_i\}$ in $M$ is related to cauchy sequence $\{b_i\}$ in $M$ if $d_M(a_i,b_i)\to 0$.  We can prove that is an equivalence relation (I think). So if $N=$ the set of all equivalence classes of cauchy sequences then if we consider each $m \in M$ as equal to the equivalence class of all cauchy sequences that converge to $m$ then $M \subset N$ and $M$ is complete.

Comment: What is $a_i-b _i$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy. I think that fleablood incorrectly has assumed that $M$ is a linear space. Just replace $a_i - b_i$ with $d_M(a_i, b_i)$.

Comment: $a_i - b_i$ is ... $a_i$ minus $b_i$.

Comment: Of course! I am just telling him that he should edit the answer.

Comment: Oops.  So I did.   Sure.  Replace it with $d_M(a_i, b_i)$.